# Invalid use of null in a Date variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this piece of code that works perfectly in a Module within VBA Microsoft Access 365 ProPlus, but when i try to use it in a Button_Click Control in a Form, shows this error:

> "Run-time error '94': Invalid use of null"

in this line:

```
RealDate = Date
```

Here's my code:

```
Sub DateTest()

Dim MyHour As String
Dim RealDate As String

MyHour = Hour(Now)

If MyHour >= 2 And MyHour <= 23 Then
RealDate = Date
Else
RealDate = Date - 1

End If

End Sub
```

Any suggestion of what could cause this error?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Regards.

Diego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put a `Date` value into a `String`, here is one way to do it:

```
If MyHour >= 2 And MyHour <= 23 Then
  RealDate = Format$(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Else
  RealDate = Format$(DateAdd("d", -1, Date), "mm/dd/yyyy")
End If
```

The "d" means "day" - it decrements the day by one if you use -1. If you are hoping to be decrementing the hour, then use "h" instead.

But also, you are defining `MyHour` as a `String`, and then comparing it to a number, which wont work either.

```
Dim MyHour As Integer
```

You can also use this to check if a variable is null or not:

```
If IsNull(Date) Then MsgBox "The Date is Null"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that code works too if i test it in a separate Module, but, when i use it in the Form Code, the value of RealDate is blank, any idea of what is happening? Could be useful if i put all my code? Regards.

Comment: It depends on how you are planning on using it. You may need to use a `Public` or `Global` definition of it, and then it wouldn't be placed within the routine.

Comment: OMG, you are so right, how did i forget that? Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here.

*First*, out of context, your code runs without errors, but makes little sense as you only set a local variable.

*Second*, `Date` can't return *Null* as it is the short form for `VBA.Date` which returns the date of today. If it can, you somehow else have a variable named Date but not declared as data type Date - but I can't give an example how that should be possible.

*Third*, don't name a string variable `RealDate` as it never will be. A "real" date value is of data type Date.

*Forth*, `Hour` returns a number, thus should not be declared as String.

So, it should go like this:

```vb
Sub DateTest()

    Dim MyHour As Integer
    Dim RealDate As Date

    MyHour = Hour(Date)

    If MyHour >= 2 And MyHour <= 23 Then
        RealDate = Date
    Else
        RealDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)    
    End If

    ' Read result.
    Debug.Print "RealDate:", RealDate

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks a lot for your input, it is really helpful to me, i'm taking into account all your feedback and my code is working fine now. Thanks again for your time.